# What is the proper and possible HttpStatus for my issue

Tags: rest, http-status-codes

Suppose I have a collection (List), which I want to perform some actions (e.g. to find available index and pass it to some injected service).

URIs -

```
/collection/index/100 BAD
/collection/index/-5  BAD
/collection/index/3   OK
```

Collection -

```
ListIndex {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

If I pass wrong index like `100` or `-5`, which `HttpStatus` should I send back to user in response? Is `406 Not Acceptable` would be a proper code?

Comment: 406 is used when a response can't be generated given  the supplied accept headers eg: you ask for XML but can't give XML. I don't think its applicable to your situation. I would use either a 404 or 500 with a response saying the item couldn't be found. More info on status codes here http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: 500 is not good here as it implies a server error. 400 is good.  I think the answer by Jean Karim is on the spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your indices are positive integers, I think -5 should get a `400 Bad Request` as it's not in the range of possible values, and 100 should get a `404 Not Found` as 100 would be a valid index but there's no actual resource at this index (yet).